# Magento 2 - How to display a programmatically created attribute under SKU on the frontend?

Tags: magento2, attributes, frontend, frontend-model

I have created a custom module, which creating an product attribute, now I need to display this attribute on the frontend, right under product SKU
[image]

How I can I do this? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a layout file  in your extension

> NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.product_vendor"
              template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.sku">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getProductVendor</argument>
                    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">product_vendor</argument>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product_vendor</argument>
                    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="product_vendor"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you please guide me how to edit this code for my module and attribute? Thanks

Comment: you can create above file in your custom theme after add above code and your custom attribute name replace to `custom_attribute`

Comment: edited, but now getting this error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor::getCustomAttribute(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml on line 37 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php:2191

Comment: give me your custom attribute name

Comment: The name is:  product_vendor

Comment: i have updated my answer you can just copy my answer and replace it

Answer (score 4):

Create a **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.cutom.attribute" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.sku">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getYourAttribute</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">your_attribute_code</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">custom_css_class</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="your_attribute_code"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```